# Order related entries by number of categories they have in common with current entry

Tags: craft3, categories

I'm creating a list of similar entries which displays entries that share the same categories as the current entry. My code looks like this:

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.relatedTo(entry) %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('projects').relatedTo( categories ).id('not ' ~ entry.id) %}
{% for project in entries %}                    
    <a href="{{ project.url }}">{{ project.title }}</a><br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Many of my entries have multiple categories. Is it possible to order the list so that entries with the most categories in common with the current entry are at the top? And if not, is there another solution that would do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Similar plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/similar) for this. I don't know that you can do it natively otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy - I'll take a look